# Perl If-Elsif-Else always going to else

Tags: perl, if-statement

I have a block of code in a larger program that is suppose to take a letter (A...D) and convert it to a number (0...3).  For some reason it always jumps down to the Else.  Here is the code:

```
        my $AA = shift @filearray;

        chomp($Q);
        chomp($A1);
        chomp($A2);
        chomp($A3);
        chomp($A4);
        chomp($AA);
        print "1:$AA\n";

    #convert answer to number

    my $AB = 0;
        if ($AA eq "A")
        {
            $AB = 0;
        }

        elsif ($AA eq "B")
        {
            $AB = 1;
        }

        elsif ($AA eq "C")
        {
            $AB = 2;
        }

        else {
            $AB = 3;
        }
        print "2:$AB\n\n";
```

The output is along the lines of

```
    1:B
    2:3

    1:A
    2:3

    1:D
    2:3

    1:C
    2:3

    1:D
    2:3

    1:B
    2:3

    1:B
    2:3

    1:A
    2:3

    1:D
    2:3
```

Now I realize at this point I could just subtract 65 from the Ascii value, but I still want to know...what is happening?

Comment: Make sure there isn't any whitespace at the end. Change your print to `print "1:$AA:"` and see if anything prints between the B and the colon.

Comment: @RaymondChen I like that idea, though when I do it I get   ::B  2:3

Comment: Also wouldn't chomp remove any whitespace?

Comment: No, at most `chomp` removes one "end-of-line" sequence (usually one of `\n`, `\n\r`, or `\r`, depending on your OS). A common issue is taking a file created on Windows (line ending `\r\n`) and processing it in Unix (line ending `\n`). A `chomp` in Linux will just remove the `\n`, leaving a `\r` at the end of every line.

Comment: @Mob after some looking on how to use regex to remove EOL characters I found the line line =~ s/[\r\n]+$//; Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe `$AA` contains an invisible characters (whitespace, carriage return). Verify that `$AA` contains what you think it does: a single character. One way to check this:

```
length($AA) == 1
```

More advanced and more informative checks include:

```
use Data::Dumper;
local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
print Dumper($AA);
```

and

```
print join ' ', map { ord } split //, $AA;
```

and

```
printf '%v02X\n', $AA;
```

The last check displays the ordinal values for every character in `$AA`.

Comment: Looks like there are indeed hidden characters. When I run what you gave I get 1:B
$VAR1 = "B\r";

66 13
42.0D\n
2:3.  Shouldn't chomp remove the \r since its whitespace?

Comment: @traisjames: Not necessarily. See my comment above.